# Add arbitrary column based on some calculation

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to add some custom values to a report and I am trying to add a column based on some logic. Is it possible to add a "cost" column based on the age range calculated from a date of birth column?

```
'Cost' AS (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy')-TO_CHAR(DOB.BIRTHDATE,'yyyy') >= 0 AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy')-TO_CHAR(DOB.BIRTHDATE,'yyyy') < 25) THEN 'Cost' =   0.05) END AS "Cost"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be

```
select
  CASE WHEN to_number(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy')) - to_number(TO_CHAR(DOB.BIRTHDATE,'yyyy')) >=  0 AND 
            to_number(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyy')) - to_number(TO_CHAR(DOB.BIRTHDATE,'yyyy')) <  25 
            THEN 0.05 
  END AS cost
from some table
```

You used wrong syntax, double quotes (where you shouldn't - that's not an error, but it's not needed either), subtracted characters.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you! I have to wait a few minutes before I can accept or up vote. I had tried this approach but didnt think of the to_number conversion.